# How can I read xml from POST to IPN system?

Tags: post, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to make a IPN system work.

They post to my url an XML.  I've tried to read it using `simplexml_load_file` but I can't.  How can i read it?

Also, is there any way of logging the referrer of the IP that is making the POST?

Comment: where do you want to read it.. which platform & language are you using..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

You should be able to get the client's IP through `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`